# OK, so I'm running a Windows Server 2008 and my friend called me an idiot for not using remote desktop to administrate it. Why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, remote-desktop

I mean, I understand that it's kind of a risk to directly log on.

But why should I just administrate it via Remote instead of directly manipulating it? :S

Answer (score 6):

Well, unless the machine is under your desk, having to get up and walk to the server room to sit down in front of the console when you don't have to seems inefficient.  I don't know if I'd go so far as to say it's *stupid*, at least comparatively speaking.

Comment: +1 for the early morning chuckle

Comment: +1 for the laziness ! And think about when you will have 50-60 servers =)

Answer (score 1):

Some things are better to do when you're right in front of the server, some are better from a remote command line and some are better from a remote GUI - it makes sense to have all of these tools in your arsenal, so think 'better for using RDP when appropriate' rather than 'an idiot for never using it' ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop has saved me a lot of trips back to work when there were troubles. Just make sure you close down the ports you don't need. Use a strong password, don't brag about the fact that you can administer the server from home. The less people know, the better.

And also don't forget that physical access is the first line of security. Make sure nobody can access the server and if you really want to lock it down, (only possible with a static IP) add a rule in the firewall, so that only your internet connection from home is allowed to connect to the RDP port over the internet.

But don't forget: if they can access the server with their hands, feet, or anything else :p then it doesn't matter what you do for security!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason other than convenience for using remote desktop over the console. 
There may be a few security related reasons to avoid using remote desktop, however.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that there is a security risk of directly logging in, there's nothing more secure than physically logging into the server. Also there is no more implicit risk of having remote desktop enabled for your server assuming you have correct account lock out policies and proper security for an internet enabled server in general.